# XCODE project compiling is very slow, source file both object-C and C++ hybrid

Tags: performance, compilation, hybrid

Using C++ interface libraries, template type, project code hybrid with object-C, current now find the compiling speed is very slow, especially for the files bind with C++, compiling for each file need 2 or 3 minutes.

ENV: XCODE 4.0.1 + GCC 4.2

Question:

1. Any factor which will cause compiling speed decline so much? What’s the root cause?
2. Based on root cause of #1, any guidance to speed it up?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this right after starting Xcode? I have found that Xcode doesn't manage memory terribly well and after using it for a couple of hours I have to restart it (or my computer) or else I have similar symptoms to those that you are describing. Restart Xcode (and maybe your computer as well) and see if that fixes your problem.